# Material UI's Stepper StepLabel Icon issue with undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

just having issues with trying to implememnt a custom Step Label Icon within the nodes of the Stepper Component provided by Material UI. I am trying to   implement an icon within  each circle, as seen here from Material UI's demo
[image]

however, am coming across an error
[image]

Please see my code below. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles, styles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const styles = theme => ({
  checklistHeader: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: '80px',
    color: 'white'
  },
  connectorIcon: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  },
  active: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});

const steps = ['Select campaign settings', 'Select campaign settings', 'Select campaign settings'];

const ColorlibStepIconRoot = styled('div')(({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? theme.palette.grey[700] : '#ccc',
  zIndex: 1,
  color: '#fff',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  display: 'flex',
  borderRadius: '50%',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  ...(ownerState.active && {
    backgroundImage:
      'linear-gradient( 136deg, rgb(242,113,33) 0%, rgb(233,64,87) 50%, rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
  }),
  ...(ownerState.completed && {
    backgroundImage:
      'linear-gradient( 136deg, rgb(242,113,33) 0%, rgb(233,64,87) 50%, rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
  }),
}));

const ColorlibStepIcon = ({
  icon, active, completed, className
}) => {
  const icons = {
    1: <Icon style={{ color: 'red' }}>create_outline</Icon>,
    2: <Icon style={{ color: 'red' }}>star</Icon>,
    3: <Icon style={{ color: 'red' }}>people</Icon>,
  };

  return (
    <ColorlibStepIconRoot ownerState={{ completed, active }} className={className}>
      {icons[String(icon)]}
    </ColorlibStepIconRoot>
  );
};

const Stepper = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h6" align="center" gutterBottom className={classes.checklistHeader}>Please complete the following criterion</Typography>
      <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={2} style={{ background: 'none' }}>
        {steps.map(label => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel StepIconComponent={ColorlibStepIcon}>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

Stepper.defaultProps = {

};

Stepper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Stepper);
```

It seems like the styled component is undefined. Is there any way that I can bypass this

Answer (score 0):

The `styled()` function is only available in v5. You either need to upgrade to MUI v5 using [this](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) installation guide or use the older API in v4, (The equivalent is `withStyles`):

**V5**

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const StyledComponent = styled(Component)({
  // your styles
});
```

**V4**

```
import { withStyles, styles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const StyledComponent = withStyles({
  // your styles
})(Component);
```

You can see the v4 docs [here](https://v4.mui.com/components/steppers/#customized-stepper) and the v5 docs [here](https://mui.com/components/steppers/#customized-horizontal-stepper).